# ExtJS3: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3, tabpanel

If we are closing a `tabPanel` using `closable: true`, the default action will be destroying the tabPanel. And so, since the tabPanel is destroyed we wont be able to display the tabPanel again. But, I do not want the tabPanel to be destroyed, it has to be hidden so I tried this

```
    this.Manage = new Ext.TabPanel({
             title: 'Manage',
             closable: true,
             closeAction: 'hide',
             activeTab: 0,
             items:[
                this.manageGridPanel

                ]
    });
```

What happens with this is, I am able to display the  tabPanel but the child elements within that are not being displayed. And I am getting following exception in js console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined` Also because of this, I am not able to navigate to other tabpanels from my treepanel, I am getting the following exception in js console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined` .

Can someone tel me How do I resolve this?

Comment: Can you reproduce it on fiddle?

Answer (score 2):

While *Pieter B* isn't right about the `closeAction` he is right about his recommendation to use the `beforeclose` event!

First let's have a look at the implementation of the `cloaseAction` property within the `Ext.Window` class, which look like this:

```
this[this.closeAction]();
```

and is used in several event callback methods.

Important is this:

> **Tab Events**
>
> There is no actual tab class — each tab is simply a Component such as
>   a Panel. However, when rendered in a TabPanel, each child Component
>   can fire additional events that only exist for tabs and are not
>   available from other Components. These events are:
>
> - *activate* : Fires when this Component becomes the active tab.
> - *deactivate* : Fires when the Component that was the active tab becomes deactivated.
> - *beforeclose* : Fires when the user clicks on the close tool of a closeable tab. ***May be vetoed by returning false from a handler.***
> - *close* : Fires a closeable tab has been closed by the user.

So <s>in theory something like</s> [this work](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/fkc):

```
new Ext.TabPanel({
    title: 'Manage',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    closable: true,
    closeAction: 'hide',
    defaults: {
        listeners: {
            'beforeclose': function(panel) {
                // We should have the tab scope here
                var closeAction = this.ownerCt.closeAction
                if (closeAction === 'hide') {
                    panel.hide();
                    Ext.get(panel.tabEl).setVisible(false);
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    },
    activeTab: 0,
    items:[
        {xtype:'panel', title: 'Tab 1', id:'tab1', closable: true, html: 'Tab 1'},
        {xtype:'panel', title: 'Tab 2', id:'tab2', closable: true, html: 'Tab 2'}
    ]
});
```

> Please notice that this is a already working snipped but you will
>   still need to fix some parts here. For example the tab el are just
>   hidden and will stay in place. For a final version you will either
>   need to remove them or set their size to zero.

Comment: Well, ExtJS3 was long ago ;) I had to edit my answer to finally get it working. The fiddle is updated to

Comment: Thanks :) Checked your fiddle, but I still get the same error though I made the changes. Should I give `tab.setVisible(true)` ?  This is how I open the tab panel dynamically,
       `if(n.text=='Manage'){
that.hometabPanel.add(manage.Manage).show();
}` should I make changes here?

Comment: @Shruti OK, you always need to define appropriate layouts and/or height/width for your components. In your example fiddle I supplied a height of 400 for the tabpanel and 200 for the childs. See my [updated fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/fkc)

Comment: Thanks, but my code does not seem to work even after making those changes, I am getting the same exception which I mentioned in the post.

Comment: @shruti Well, I can't tell anything about these errors without seeing them in a fiddle. But the example should help you anyway, because it works, even with content. Taking a wild guess is, that you work to much with variables and kills one of your rendered components that way. But like a said, this is just a wild guess...

Answer (score -1):

I don't think `closeAction` is meant to be used.

You could instead use the event `beforeclose`, hide the `tabpanel` in the listener and return `false` to disable the close event.

Comment: `closeAction:'hide'` property works in case of `window`, i was looking for something similar for `tabpanel`